# Hide Table row which contain status as moving, ignition on

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, rows

```
<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >21</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56155</td>
    <td>77.05239</td>
    <td>06:09:27</td>
    <td>Start</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >22</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56151</td>
    <td>77.05234</td>
    <td>06:09:37</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >23</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56148</td>
    <td>77.05230</td>
    <td>06:09:47</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >24</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56146</td>
    <td>77.05229</td>
    <td>06:09:56</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >25</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56146</td>
    <td>77.05230</td>
    <td>06:10:06</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >26</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56146</td>
    <td>77.05230</td>
    <td>06:10:16</td>
    <td>Stop</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >27</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56148</td>
    <td>77.05230</td>
    <td>06:10:26</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >28</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56150</td>
    <td>77.05229</td>
    <td>06:10:36</td>
    <td>Start</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >29</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56152</td>
    <td>77.05233</td>
    <td>06:10:45</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >30</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56154</td>
    <td>77.05238</td>
    <td>06:10:55</td>
    <td>Stop</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >31</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56155</td>
    <td>77.05242</td>
    <td>06:11:05</td>
    <td>Ignition_On</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>


<tr  >
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td >32</td>
    <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
    <td>28.56152</td>
    <td>77.05241</td>
    <td>06:11:15</td>
    <td>Start</td>
    <td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick="Edit()"   /> <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/></td>
</tr>
```

I want hide table row which contain at status column Moving, ignition on point using Javascript, because I want only stop and start point on table. Actually this data fetch from a xml site using Java at server side.

Comment: Can u plz upvote my answer as well?  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/76Bfn/).

```
$("td:contains('Moving')")
    .closest('tr')
    .add(
        $("td:contains('Ignition_On')").closest('tr')
    ).addClass('delete');
```

So, instead of `.addClass()` you can use `.remove()` or `.hide()` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/76Bfn/1/)

Comment: and i want also remove Arrive,Location

Answer (score 0):

That should do the work

```
$("td:contains('Ignition_On')").closest('tr').css('display', 'none');

http://jsfiddle.net/KuvG7/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can do the following.

```
$("tr td:contains('Ignition_On')").each(function(){ 
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```